# Криво генерируется человекопонятный URL

Tags: php, yii

В правилах `urlManager` прописал:

```
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>/<name:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
```

Генерирую URL:

```
$this->createUrl('article/tag', ['id' => $model->id, 'name' => $model->name]); //$model->id=1; $model->name='newname'
```

Ожидаю такой URL: `http://domain.ru/article/tag/1/newname`
Но получаю такой: `http://domain.ru/article/tag/1/?name=newname`

Похоже, что второе правило попросту не задействуется.
Попробовал убрать первое правило, и URL сформировался как надо, но на страницах с URL без параметра `name` (например `http://domain.ru/article/tag/1`) если я хочу получить доступ к `$_GET['id']` вылетает ошибка `Undefined index: id`. Короче говоря, работают ссылки только тогда, когда есть 2 параметра

Comment: Перед этим правилом есть еще какие-нибудь? В случае, если роутер находит мало-мальски подходящее совпадение, он прекращает поиск.

Comment: @Etki спасибо, перед ним было такое же правило, только без параметра name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему, разместив правила в обратном порядке.